# how to Convert org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject to my customJavaObject

Tags: java, xml, apache, xsd, xmlbeans

I am having a method where I am receiving XmlObject as an argument in the method and now I want to convert it into the java corresponding java object , that I have to pass in other webservice.

I have tried all the possible ways but not able to get it.

Code :

```
public static boolean updateAddress_V2(XmlObject xmlObject) throws XmlException{
         AlarsDataService dataService=new AlarsDataService();
         CustomerV2 customerV2=CustomerV2.Factory.parse(xmlObject.toString());
         com.alars.osb.java.customer.CustomerV2.Customer customerXML=customerV2.getCustomer();
}
```

but when I am checking customerXML is coming as null.

Here is the XMLObject string value :

```
 <Customer_V2 xmlns="http://www.alars.com/osb/java/Customer">
  <Customer>
    <customerId>4</customerId>
    <driverLicense>XBRT245</driverLicense>
    <firstName>ALEX</firstName>
    <lastName>CINTRA</lastName>
    <dob>21-11-1986</dob>
    <addressLine1>10 Florence St</addressLine1>
    <city>BOSTON</city>
    <zipCode>02148</zipCode>
  </Customer>
</Customer_V2>
```

Customer XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.alars.com/osb/java/Customer"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.alars.com/osb/java/Citation" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="Customer">
        <sequence>
            <element name="customerId" type="long"></element>
            <element name="driverLicense" type="string"></element>
            <element name="firstName" type="string"></element>
            <element name="lastName" type="string"></element>
            <element name="dob" type="date"></element>
            <element name="addressLine1" type="string"></element>
            <element name="city" type="string"></element>
            <element name="zipCode" type="string"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="Customer_V2">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Customer">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="customerId" type="long"></element>
                        <element name="driverLicense" type="string"></element>
                        <element name="firstName" type="string"></element>
                        <element name="lastName" type="string"></element>
                        <element name="dob" type="date"></element>
                        <element name="addressLine1" type="string"></element>
                        <element name="city" type="string"></element>
                        <element name="zipCode" type="string"></element>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Any advise folks.. how to achieve this ??

Comment: My guess is that either your parser is broken, or the syntax of your XML is broken. How flexible is this parser? Can we see it? From what we know, that code works perfectly and you're lying (read: there are no syntax errors, assuming your classes exists).

Comment: Updated the question to include my customer.xsd.

Comment: I don't see any changes :) (There we go)

Comment: I am using ant script to generate the classes. CustomerV2 and Customer are generated through that script only.

Comment: I have never worked with this before, but I wonder if you aren't required to specify `driverLicense`, `firstName`, `lastName` and `dob`, too, since it's in the sequence (in which my common sense - the only thing I can rely on here - is telling me those fields are expected).

Comment: I tried by passing all the XML values , but still same issue.
Anyways thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You change the schema type of XmlObject to required CustomerV2 as follows since we do not know the type ahead.

```
CustomerV2 customerV2 = (CustomerV2)
xmlObject.changeType(CustomerV2.type);
```

To check the schema type against the required CustomerV2 schema type, you can do the following.

```
xmlObject.schemaType().isAssignableFrom(CustomerV2 .type);
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML does not match to the XSD. Especially, the XSD is missing the top `element` entries. Use following Schema instead and re-generate your XMLBeans classes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.alars.com/osb/java/Customer" xmlns:customer="http://www.alars.com/osb/java/Customer">
<xs:element name="CustomerParent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="customer:Customer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Customer">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="customer:customerId"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:driverLicense"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:firstName"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:lastName"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:dob"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:addressLine1"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:city"/>
            <xs:element ref="customer:zipCode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="driverLicense" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="dob" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
    <xs:element name="addressLine1" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:element name="zipCode" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Parse your XML as follows:

```
final CustomerParentDocument customerParentV1 = CustomerParentDocument.Factory.parse(file);
```

Comment: @tech-idiot I update my answer. Perhaps you may have look at it.